# unable to ckeck cookie is available or not in .net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

In .NET MVC is there anyway to check if a cookie exists or not.  I just want to access my available cookies before use.  But when checking its giving me an error  =>

my code ----

```
internal User CheckCookieUser()
{
        User cookieuser = null;
        string UserId, password = null;
        if(Request.Cookies["TSMSUserId"] != null && Request.Cookies["TSMSpassword"] != null)
        {
            UserId = Request.Cookies["TSMSUserId"].Value;
            password = Request.Cookies["TSMSpassword"].Value;

            User olduserdata = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == UserId && x.password == password).SingleOrDefault();

            if (olduserdata == null)
            {
                return cookieuser;
            }

            cookieuser = new User { UserId = UserId, password = password, level = olduserdata.level }; 
        }
        return cookieuser;
}
```

I have searched for but have not found a solution to the problem.

Problem that is showing in the browser =>

[image: browser problem]

and what i found after debug =>

[image: Visual Studio Debug]

Why is this exception arising. Isn't there any way to check if the cookie exists or not, or is my approach wrong.

Comment: It is a bad practice to store the password in the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Yous should check request as well.

```
 if (Request != null &&Request.Cookies["TSMSUserId"] != null && Request.Cookies["TSMSpassword"] != null)
```

Comment: It will not be there untill unless user will action.

Answer (score 0):

1) make sure you are calling this function from controller action. That is after request context got initialized. If not then also check request!=null.

2) try using fully qualified name for request including name space. Something like system.web.httpcontext.current.request.

Sorry for typos. Answered from mobile.

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

1) Add `using System.Web;` at the top of that class file

2) update your code as given below

```
internal User CheckCookieUser()
{
        User cookieuser = null;
        string UserId, password = null;
        if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["TSMSUserId"] != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["TSMSpassword"] != null)
        {
            UserId = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["TSMSUserId"].Value;
            password = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["TSMSpassword"].Value;

            User olduserdata = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == UserId && x.password == password).SingleOrDefault();

            if (olduserdata == null)
            {
                return cookieuser;
            }

            cookieuser = new User { UserId = UserId, password = password, level = olduserdata.level }; 
        }
        return cookieuser;
}
```